# how to transfer files that match a pattern with rsync

Tags: bash, rsync, quotes

Good morning,
I want to transfer specific files in a directory to a remote machine while keeping the architecture of the subdirectories. Moreover, I only want to transfer files that have a peculiar extension (e.g. ".txt").
I have tried the following:

```
rsync -aP --include *.txt ./sourceDirectory user@hostIP:destDirectory
```

but it copies to the destination (`destDirectory`) all the files, and not only those which match the `.txt` pattern.
Could anybody help me with such riddle?

P.S.: obviously, the directory `sourceDirectory` contains subdirectories where are located my `.txt` files.

Comment: It's a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421566/rsync-only-files-matching-pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to have the same problem when rsync videos to home NAS. If you read the manual of rsync, the `--include` flag really means "Do not exclude". It actually has to work together with a `--exclude` flag.

The follow command will do your job:

```
rsync -aP --include="*/" --include="*.txt" --exclude="*" sourceDirectory destDirectory
```

The command literally means exclude everything, except for subfolders and txt file.